# Add a PWA Enterprise Custom Field to Project Pro

Tags: ms-project-2013

I've added an Enterprise Custom Field to tasks in Project Web Access (under Sharepoint 2013) but when I open an existing project published on PWA in Project Pro 2013 I don't see the new field.

It doesn't appear in the Project > Custom Fields Dialog, nor does it appear when I right-click the header of a task list column and choose Insert Column.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the custom field in PWA you need to close Project Pro completely. It is not enough to just close the project you are working on. When you then re-open Project Pro, re-open the project in question and check it out the additional field should appear in both places.

You should publish and check in the project to keep this new field in the instance of the project.